# Python brkLyr.supports ("dataSource") Error?

Tags: arcpy, attributeerror

This is supposed to loop through a directory of MXD's and look for broken links and create a report. I am getting an error, an exception I believe, on one of the data sources. In the MXD it shows a data path (broken) in the properties, and the feature class should support a source, so what could cause this?

It's interesting that all the sources first point to the local machines instance of ArcCatalog followed by the actual SDE path.

Does that look right?

Could that have something to do with the issue?

Many other MXD's and layers are worked fine and were reported before crashing. If I pull out just this layer and/ or mxd I usualy get the same error in other places too, including stand alone tables. The failed featurclass does not have any joins or relates.

Any guesses at whats going on?

Error message
[image: Source Error]

Last line of report:
[image: Failed Report]

```
print "Importing Modules"
import arcpy, datetime, time, os

date = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")

print "Setting Variables"
mxd_Paths = []
output = os.path.join (r"S:\Departments\GIS\Data\Admin\Dev\PYTHON\Testing\Reports\Broken_Portal_Links", date + ".txt")

print "Building Lists"
#Populate mxd_Paths
exclude = ("BAK")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\Corey.Fields\Python\Testing\Test_2"):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".mxd"):
            mxd_Paths.append(os.path.join(root, file,))

#Create r/w output text file
print "Opening Output"
outFile = open(output, 'w')

#Report header
print "Writing Header"
outFile.write("Data Source Report: \n")
outFile.write(" \n")
outFile.write("This report summarizes the names of the individual layers within a map document \n")
outFile.write("that does not have a valid data source. \n")
outFile.write(" \n")
outFile.write("Date: " + str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")) + "\n")

#Reference MXD files
print "Finding Broken Sources"
for mxd in mxd_Paths:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd)
    mxdName = os.path.basename(mxd.filePath).split(".mxd")
    count = 0
    print mxd



    #Report broken sources
    print "Report broken sources"

    #If at least one data source within mxd is broken then:
    if len(arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd)) > 0:
        count = count + 1

    #Print the name of the mxd to Text file
    print "Printing MXD"
    outFile.write("\n")
    outFile.write("\n")
    outFile.write("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n")
    outFile.write(" MAPDOCUMENT: " + os.path.basename(mxd.filePath) + "\n")
    outFile.write("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n")
    outFile.write(" \n")

    #Array of all layers that have broken data sources, so we can get a count of how many data sources are broken.
    print "... # of Broken Sources"
    BDS = arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd)

    #Print the number of broken data sources by counting how many objects make up the BDS array.
    outFile.write("Number Broken Data Source(s): " + str(len(BDS)) )
    outFile.write(" \n")
    outFile.write(" \n")

    #Loop through each broken data source
    print "... Write Broken"
    for brkLyr in arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd):
    #If the broken data source is actually a data source then print the name and original data source location.
        if brkLyr.supports("dataSource"):
            outFile.write("\t Layer name:      " + brkLyr.name + "\n")
            outFile.write("\t Original source: " + brkLyr.dataSource + "\n")
        else:
            outFile.write("\t Layer name:      " + brkLyr.name + "\n")
            outFile.write("\t Original source: " + "No Source" + "\n")

    #Delete locks on the mxd
    del mxd


#Report if no broken sources are found
if count == 0:
    outFile.write("\n")
    outFile.write("\n")
    outFile.write("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n")
    outFile.write("              NO BROKEN DATA SOURCES FOUND \n")
    outFile.write("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n")

#Print the count
print "Printing count"
outFile.write("\n")
outFile.write("\n")
outFile.write("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n")
outFile.write(" Total number of broken sources: " + count + "\n")
outFile.write("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n")
outFile.write("\n")
outFile.write("\n")
outFile.write("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n")
outFile.write("    END OF REPORT" + "\n")
outFile.write("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- \n")
outFile.write(" \n")

#Close the file
outFile.close()

#Open the resulting output text file
os.startfile(output)

#Delete all variables that reference data on disk
del mxd_Paths, output, outFile
```

Comment: Please always provide error messages as text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TableView (assuming what was found in the MXD was a table) points to a table. And a tableview doesn't have the same methods as a layer.

Per the doc, [TableView](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/TableView/00s300000017000000/) doesn't have a "supports" method. It looks like the ListBrokenDataSources property returns both layers and tables. Its because of that you're getting into a situation where you're calling a method on a type that doesn't have it.

If you don't care about tables you could wrap the If statements in Try/Excepts and just pass on them. Or if you do care about reporting them it looks like you'll need to test for a layer or table before doing the supports check. (then only doing supports on layers)

```
for brkLyr in arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd):
#If the broken data source is actually a data source then print the name and original data source location.
    try:
      if brkLyr.supports("dataSource"):
          outFile.write("\t Layer name:      " + brkLyr.name + "\n")
          outFile.write("\t Original source: " + brkLyr.dataSource + "\n")
      else:
          outFile.write("\t Layer name:      " + brkLyr.name + "\n")
          outFile.write("\t Original source: " + "No Source" + "\n")
    except:
      print "i dont care about tables"
```

or

```
for brkLyr in arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(mxd):
#If the broken data source is actually a data source then print the name and original data source location.
    if type(brkLyr) is arcpy.mapping.Layer:
      if brkLyr.supports("dataSource"):
          outFile.write("\t Layer name:      " + brkLyr.name + "\n")
          outFile.write("\t Original source: " + brkLyr.dataSource + "\n")
      else:
          outFile.write("\t Layer name:      " + brkLyr.name + "\n")
          outFile.write("\t Original source: " + "No Source" + "\n")
    if type(brkLyr) is arcpy.mapping.TableView:
      #do checks...
```